# Getting IBotState for new GDPR methods

Tags: botframework

Microsoft blogged about GDPR compliance for Bot Framework today - https://blog.botframework.com/2018/04/23/general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/.

Have a had a go at implementing (https://github.com/leeroy79/GDPRBot) but coming up against a few hurdles. Their provided sample relies on the deprecated state service so wondering about alternatives.

Part 1 - 
Specifically - how can we get an `IBotState` or `IConversations` (which 3 of the mentioned GDPR methods operate on) without using State Client, either within the bot or in an external website as recommended?

Part 2 - 
Also any thoughts on how to clear conversation / user / private conversation data for one specific user given the mentioned methods `SetUserData()` and `SetPrivateConversationData()` are both deprecated?

I've tried the following but it doesn't actually clear the state. I can directly do `context.UserData.Clear()` and `context.PrivateConversationData.Clear()` but that won't work when this code is moved to a standalone website and `context` isn't available as suggested in the GDPR post.

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, context.Activity.AsMessageActivity()))
{
    var dataStore = scope.Resolve<IBotDataStore<BotData>>();

    var address = new Address(
       context.Activity.Recipient.Id,
       context.Activity.ChannelId,
       context.Activity.From.Id,
       context.Activity.Conversation.Id,
       context.Activity.ServiceUrl);

    var token = default(CancellationToken);

    await dataStore.SaveAsync(address, BotStoreType.BotUserData, null, token);
    await dataStore.SaveAsync(address, BotStoreType.BotPrivateConversationData, null, token);
    await dataStore.FlushAsync(address, token);
}
```

Cheers

Lee

Answer (score 2):

> how can we get an `IBotState` or `IConversations` (which 3 of the
> mentioned GDPR methods operate on) without using State Client, either
> within the bot or in an external website as recommended?

The State Client is not deprecated, it's the initial implementation provided by Microsoft which is (sometimes called `Bot State Service`).

Once you migrated your bot code to use your own storage (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)), for example Azure Table Storage or Cosmos DB, you should use `IBotDataStore<BotData>` interface to manipulate your data.

> Also any thoughts on how to clear conversation / user / private
> conversation data for one specific user given the mentioned methods
> `SetUserData()` and `SetPrivateConversationData()` are both deprecated?

You have to use `IBotDataStore<BotData>` interface methods:

```
public interface IBotDataStore<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return BotData with Data pointing to a JObject or an empty BotData() record with ETag:""
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"> The key.</param>
    /// <param name="botStoreType"> The bot store type.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"> The cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>Bot record that is stored for this key, or "empty" bot record ready to be stored</returns>
    Task<T> LoadAsync(IAddress key, BotStoreType botStoreType, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    /// <summary>
    /// Save a BotData using the ETag.
    /// Etag consistency checks
    ///     If ETag is null or empty, this will set the value if nobody has set it yet
    ///     If ETag is "*" then this will unconditionally set the value
    ///     If ETag matches then this will update the value if it is unchanged.
    /// If Data is null this removes record, otherwise it stores
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"> The key.</param>
    /// <param name="botStoreType">The bot store type.</param>
    /// <param name="data"> The data that should be saved.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"> The cancellation token.</param>
    /// <returns>throw HttpException(HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed) if update fails</returns>
    Task SaveAsync(IAddress key, BotStoreType botStoreType, T data, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    Task<bool> FlushAsync(IAddress key, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

Those methods are generic for user / privateConversation / conversation data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You're right, behind the scenes I'm resolving `IBotDataStore<BotData>` to `TableBotDataStore` to use Azure for bot state. When I then call `context.Activity.GetStateClient()`, `myStateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync()` and `myUserData.SetProperty()` I don't get the yellow warning in the emulator which you get when you're using the default state implementation.

But `StateClient` class and `GetUserDataAsync()` are both marked Obsolete in the latest Bot Framework code. Any idea if there is an alternative to using them or do we just have to live with the warning?

Comment: Thanks mate, has shed some light on how this works. Still having some issues actually clearing it as I've indicated in my edited original post.